# C# Console Program Linq Error When Trying to Read "Press any key to continue"

Tags: c#

I have

```
Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
```

I am trying to get this to work with the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> details = new List<string>();
            Console.Write("Enter First Name: ");
            details.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter Last Name: ");
            details.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter Street: ");
            details.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter City: ");
            details.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter State: ");
            details.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter Zip: ");
            details.Add(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nCustomer's Information:");

            var result = from detail in details
                         let upperCaseWord = UppercaseWords(detail)
                         select upperCaseWord;

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string UppercaseWords(string value)
        {
            char[] array = value.ToCharArray();

            if (array.Length >= 1)
            {
                if (char.IsLower(array[0]))
                {
                    array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i - 1] == ' ')
                {
                    if (char.IsLower(array[i]))
                    {
                        array[i] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return new string(array);
        }
    }
}
```

Wherever I put in the

```
Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
```

it causes an error or it displays incorrectly (before the words, in the middle of the words, but not at the very end of the page where it should). I know this seems like a simple issue, but I am very confused and lost. I cannot seem to figure out what I have done wrong here? Any help would be wonderful!

This is for an assignment that is supposed to:

1. Create a string List.
2. Use Console.ReadLine() to collect values of firstName, lastName, street, city, state, zip, save them to List.
3. Write a simple Linq statement, call method UppercaseWords() to change first letter to uppercase.
4. Create a foreach statement to display the information.

So I believe I have everything working otherwise, but I am lost as to why what should be the simplest part of the program will not work.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Where did you put "Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");" lines?

Comment: It ended up working after I put it between here. I am not sure if this is correct though?            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n"); //so it shows a space
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static string UppercaseWords(string value)

Comment: It’s a bad idea to end the Console main function with a ReadLine, because if you run the program from the command prompt (what console programs are intended for) it will still wait for a user-input and the end for no reason as the console will stay open, which from a user perspective is unnecessary and thus annoying. Just remove the ReadLine and the “Press any key to continue” and if you start your program in Visual Studio use Ctrl+F5 instead of just F5 which will leave the console window open and automatically print the Press-any-key-message.

Answer (score -1):

Since you said, "Any help would be really appreciated", I thought I would take some time to share a few ideas on how to make your program much better. I am not saying this is the only way to do it or even the best way, but hopefully, it gives you something to think about and improve your skills.

One of your goals as a programmer should be to write as little code as necessary. Here is some of your code doing the same thing repeatedly, with only a slight change.

```
   Console.Write("Enter First Name: ");
   details.Add(Console.ReadLine());
   Console.Write("Enter Last Name: ");
   details.Add(Console.ReadLine());
```

By getting rid of all the repeated code we can make this better: First thing to notice is that the only difference is the "Name" of the data you are inputting, so collect all the names into 1 place:

```
//static - only 1 copy of this data is ever needed
//readonly - these values should never be changed
static readonly List<string> DataNames = new List<string>() { "First Name", "Last Name", 
                                                              "Street", "City", "State", "Zip"};
```

Now write a function that can input a value:

```
static string ReadDataPairFromConsole( string DataName )
{
    Console.Write("Enter {0}: ", DataName );
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now all of the data can be input with a single line:

```
DataNames.ForEach(name => details.Add(ReadDataPairFromConsole(name)));
```

Since each word needs to be UpperCased the code could follow the logic you wrote and process the entire input list. However, it is also possible to process each input as it is entered doing something like this:

```
static string ReadDataPairFromConsole( string DataName )
{
    Console.Write("Enter {0}: ", DataName );
    return FirstLetterUpper(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

You can also take advantage of built-in functions to do FirstLetterUpper on a single word(there are a couple edge cases that this does not check):

```
 var upWord = char.ToUpper(InputString[0]) + InputString.Substring(1);
```

There are many other changes I would make, such as using  pairs to keep the input label matched with the input string. Then when the data is output it is known what each piece is.

I wish you the best in your studies.